# Why is my list mutating because of a print statement in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a CodeAcademy activity where I zipped two lists together. I get different print results depending on the order they are placed.

```
names = ["Mohamed", "Sara", "Xia", "Paul", "Valentina", "Jide", "Aaron", "Emily", "Nikita", "Paul"]
insurance_costs = [13262.0, 4816.0, 6839.0, 5054.0, 14724.0, 5360.0, 7640.0, 6072.0, 2750.0, 12064.0]

medical_records = zip(insurance_costs, names)

print (list(medical_records))

num_medical_records = len(list(medical_records))

print(num_medical_records)
```

When I print I get the expected list, but the num_medical_records is 0? If I switch the order of my print statements, the result is an empty list, but printing num_medical_records gives me the correct number "11".

```
medical_records = zip(insurance_costs, names)

num_medical_records = len(list(medical_records))

print (list(medical_records))

print(num_medical_records)
```

Why is medical_records mutating? Greatly appreciate your insight!

Comment: You aren't mutating a list. You are mutating your `zip` object, which is an iterator, and you use `list(medical_records)`, which exhausts the iterator

Answer (score 1):

I believe `zip` returns an iterator. When you call `list(medical_records)`, you exhaust the iterator. That's why calling `len(list(medical_records))` gets no result because there's nothing to yield.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Answer (score 0):

You should first save the `zip(insurance_costs, names)` into a list, e.g.

`zipped_list = list(zip(insurance_costs, names))`

then perform other actions on the `zipped_list` variable, under which a list is stored. The `zip` creates an iterator only, which is exhausted by the first function run on it.

Answer (score 0):

The zip function can only be iterated over only once.

You can do something like this:

```py
names = ["Mohamed", "Sara", "Xia", "Paul", "Valentina", "Jide", "Aaron", "Emily", "Nikita", "Paul"]
insurance_costs = [13262.0, 4816.0, 6839.0, 5054.0, 14724.0, 5360.0, 7640.0, 6072.0, 2750.0, 12064.0]

medical_records = list(zip(insurance_costs, names))

print (medical_records)

num_medical_records = len(medical_records)

print(num_medical_records)
```